# Constructing Map in EL JSP

Tags: java, jsp, el

I came across the following code and looks like it is constructing a map but I cannot find a reference anywhere.

```
actionParams="${ format.asMap( 'name', 'me-popover-'.concat( name ), 'position', 'triggerBottom' ) }"
```

My use case is very similar that I need to construct a map from in the JSP. I do not want to pass this information from java as we made a decision to make static content to JSP files and and dynamic from java to keep the business logic simple.

Is there any way to create a map in JSP without using scriptlets?

Comment: How is `format` declared?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the following method:

```
public Map<String, String> asMap(String... elements) {
    int n = elements.length;
    if (n % 2 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot handle an odd number of elements");
    }
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2) {
        String key = elements[i];
        String value = elements[i + 1];
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

In your JSP, declare a bean:

```
<jsp:useBean id="format" class="package.to.the.CreatedClass" />
```

Then the code you provided should work.